# Collection Select in HAML fails to wrap correctly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Does anyone know why

```
%select{:name => "dropdown"} expand »
- for say_text in @available_says
%option = h say_text
```

in HAML resolves to

```
<select name='dropdown'></select>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
```

in HTML? It's stymieing my dropdown completely and the documentation all says "That should work."  I can't indent the third line properly because the HAML code explodes at that point.  This is in Rails 2.3.8, btw.

Answer (score 6):

You need to reflect the document structure with correct indentation.

```
%select{:name => "dropdown"}
  - for say_text in @available_says
    %option= h say_text
```